# In Python I want to join several csv files into one csv file. I get the error: "first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed ..."

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to join a number of csv files into 1 large csv file.
I get the error message:

> first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an
> object of type "DataFrame"

My code is

```
en_tweet_file = 'en_tweets.csv'
create_file(en_tweet_file)
csv1 = pd.read_csv(en_tweet_file)
list_dirs = os.listdir()
for _dir in list_dirs:
    print(f"Append {_dir}")
    csv2 = pd.read_csv(f"{_dir}/tweets.csv")
    csv1 = pd.concat(csv1, csv2)
    csv1.to_csv(en_tweet_file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `big_df = pd.concat( [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(_dir,'tweets.csv')) for _dir in list_dirs]) `

Comment: [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) requires a list of dataframes as input, eg `pd.concat([csv1, csv2])`.

Comment: Thank you Dimitry and RJ, it is working now